# Inserting HTML anchor target="_blank" into a PHP echo statement

Tags: php, html, anchor

This is my first time using stackoverflow, so I apologize if I did anything incorrectly. The title says it all: I need to insert a target="_blank" (or make two of these six links open in a new window/tab) into this php echo statement without removing any of the php code. The second and fourth list items are the links I'm trying to change. I'm using [TomatoCart](http://tomatocart.com/) if that helps at all.

```
    <?php
      echo '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'index' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'index' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span>' . osc_link_object(osc_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'index'), $osC_Language->get('home')) . '<span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>' .
           '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'info' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'articles' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span>' . osc_link_object(osc_href_link('http://www.acehardwaretexas.com/files/circular/index.html'), $osC_Language->get('promos')) . '<span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>' .
           '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'info' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'articles' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span>' . osc_link_object(osc_href_link(FILENAME_INFO, 'articles&articles_id=1'), $osC_Language->get('services')) . '<span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>' .
           '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'info' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'articles' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span>' . osc_link_object(osc_href_link('https://www.acehardware.com/acerewards'), $osC_Language->get('rewards')) . '<span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>' .
           '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'info' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'articles' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span>' . osc_link_object(osc_href_link(FILENAME_INFO, 'articles&articles_id=2'), $osC_Language->get('hours')) . '<span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>' .
           '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'info' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'contact' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span>' . osc_link_object(osc_href_link(FILENAME_INFO, 'contact'), $osC_Language->get('contact_us')) . '<span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Why not replace the `osc_link_object(osc_href_link` with an anchor tag and URL?

Comment: Don't forget to [insert a `rel="noopener"`](https://techstacker.com/html-noopener-attribute/) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run str_replace over the osc_link_object function and replace `<a` with `<a target="_blank"`

For example, the second link could be

```
'<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'info' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'articles' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span>' . str_replace("<a ", "<a target='_blank' ", osc_link_object(osc_href_link('http://www.acehardwaretexas.com/files/circular/index.html'), $osC_Language->get('promos'))) . '<span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>' .
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm, and all I had to do was paste in `str_replace("<a ", "<a target='_blank' ",` and an extra parentheses!

Answer (score 0):

Replaced link objects with anchor tags.

```
<?php
  echo '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'index' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'index' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span><a target="_blank" href="index">home</a><span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>' .
       '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'info' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'articles' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span><a target="_blank" href="http://www.acehardwaretexas.com/files/circular/index.html">promos</a><span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>' .
       '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'info' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'articles' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span<a target="_blank" href="articles&articles_id=1">services</a><span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>' .
       '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'info' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'articles' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span><a target="_blank" href="https://www.acehardware.com/acerewards">rewards</a><span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>' .
       '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'info' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'articles' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span><a target="_blank" href="articles&articles_id=2">hours</a><span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>' .
       '<li ' . ($osC_Template->getGroup() == 'info' && $osC_Template->getModule() == 'contact' ? 'class="navVisited"' : null) . '><span class="navLeftHook">&nbsp;</span><a target="_blank" href="contact">contact_us</a><span class="navHoverDownHook">&nbsp;</span><span class="navRightHook">&nbsp;</span></li>';
?>
```

Comment: I chose dave's answer, because I was trying to insert the `target="_blank"` without removing any PHP. Thank you for your response though!